# Replace a value in a dataframe with the row name

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, rows

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
         Jill Jimmie Alex Jane 
    Jill   1    0      1    1    
    Jimmie 0    1      1    0    
    Alex   0    1      1    0    
    Jane   1    1      1    0
```

I want to change every 1 to its corresponding row name, such as this:

```
         Jill Jimmie Alex Jane 
    Jill Jill    0   Jill  Jill  
    Jimmie 0  Jimmie Jimmie 0   
    Alex   0   Alex  Alex   0   
    Jane Jane  Jane  Jane   0
```

After that, I want to remove all zeros from the data frame and move up the values in the columns.

I've tried:

```
    # for (i in ibm_data){
    #   if (ibm_data == 1){
    #     names <- row.names(i)
    #     ibm_data[ibm_data == 1] <- names
    #   }
    #   else{
    #     ibm_data[ibm_data == 0] <- "NA"
    #   }
    # }
```

And then I would remove by `NA` values, but I think I am making this overly complicated. I plan to build a forced graph from the list of names to see correlations.

Comment: All values from a single column in a data.frame must have the same class, you can't mix numeric and character objects. Or try `as.character` in each of your column before and compare with `== "1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `replace/row`

```
df1[] <- replace(row.names(df1)[row(df1)*(NA^!df1)], !df1, 0)
df1
#       Jill Jimmie   Alex Jane
#Jill   Jill      0   Jill Jill
#Jimmie    0 Jimmie Jimmie    0
#Alex      0   Alex   Alex    0
#Jane   Jane   Jane   Jane    0
```

The idea is to get the row index of the rows with `row` function, replace the index where it is 0 in the original `data.frame` to NA, use that index to get the corresponding row names, and `replace` the NA to 0 by using the logical matrix (`!df1` - returns TRUE where there are 0 values and FALSE for 1)

---

Or a more straightforward way is

```
df1[] <- replace(row.names(df1)[row(df1)], !df1, 0)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Jill = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Jimmie = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Alex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Jane = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Jill", 
"Jimmie", "Alex", "Jane"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Jill", 
"Jimmie", "Alex", "Jane"))
```

Comment: Am I manifesting this in a for loop to run through all my data, because as of right now I'm not getting any changes?

Comment: @sgatta Did you meant that you wanted `for` loop solutions?  Based on the data I showed, it is changing

Comment: It's working now! It was an error on my side.I'll mark you as my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @sgatta Try with the 'data' in my post and the code to check if you get the expected results.  May be your data is not `numeric` and perhaps `factor` class?

Comment: Real quick, the names change, but the 0's still exist. How do i remove them and move the values up?

Comment: @sgatta Your expected output seems to have 0's at the same location.  If you want to move up, means you may loop through `lapply` i.e. `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) c(x[x!=0], x[x==0]))` but then the row names will not be in the same position

Answer (score 2):

I think this accomplishes both the filling in of the rownames for cell values with 1 as well as removing "all zeros from the data frame and move up the values in the columns."

This returns a named list where each list element is the corresponding column and the values are the rownames for which the value in the column is equal to 1.

```
lapply(dat, function(x) rownames(dat)[x==1])
$Jill
[1] "Jill" "Jane"

$Jimmie
[1] "Jimmie" "Alex"   "Jane"  

$Alex
[1] "Jill"   "Jimmie" "Alex"   "Jane"  

$Jane
[1] "Jill"
```

Answer (score 1):

While I like the @akrun's one-liner I want to post a more elaborated answer:

```
k <- which(df==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
df[k] <- rownames(k)

df

#        Jill Jimmie   Alex Jane 
# Jill   Jill      0   Jill Jill 
# Jimmie    0 Jimmie Jimmie    0 
# Alex      0   Alex   Alex    0 
# Jane   Jane   Jane   Jane    0
```

***Data***

```
read.table(text='Jill Jimmie Alex Jane 
       Jill   1    0      1    1    
       Jimmie 0    1      1    0    
       Alex   0    1      1    0    
       Jane   1    1      1    0 ', header = T, quote ='"') -> df
```