# Replace value in dataframe with row names while taking transpose

Tags: r

I've a dataframe as below

```
    X   Y   Z
A   *       
B           
C   *       
D           
E           
F   *       
G   *       
H           *
I   *   *
```

I want to change the column names to rows such that its repeated with the original rows for the number of times theres a star in the cell

The resulting output is as below

```
School  Agency
X   A
X   C
X   F
X   G
X   I
Y   I
Z   *
```

I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218214/replace-a-value-in-a-dataframe-with-the-row-name) but it has the same row and column names so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the row/column index with `arr.ind` in `which` on the logical `matrix`, and get the corresponding row names and column names

```
i1 <- which(dat == "*", arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(School = colnames(dat)[i1[,2]], Agency = row.names(dat)[i1[,1]])
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(X = c("*", "", "*", "", "", "*", "*", "", "*"), 
Y = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "*"), Z = c("", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "*", "")), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", 
 "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), class = "data.frame")
```